# Error: Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: linq

Below is my code. I am trying to get the company list and also employee list under each company. But below code is throwing error

> Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.

Please help.

```
public class Company {
    public int CompID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public List<Employees> EmplList { get; set; }
}

public class Employees {
    public int EMPID { get; set; }
    public string EMPNAME { get; set; }
}

var empllist = (from c in Db.Company select new Company {
    CompID = c.ID,
    CompanyName = c.Name,
    EmplList = new List<Employees> (
        from e in Db.Employee
        where c.ID == e.ID
        select new Employees {
            EMPID = e.ID,
            EMPNAME = e.Name
        })
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Code

```
var empllist = (from c in Db.Company
                        select new Company
                        {
                            CompID = c.ID,
                            CompanyName = c.Name,
                            EmplList =  Db.Employee.where(k=>k.EMPID =c.CompID ).select(m=> new Employees{EMPID = m.EMPID,EMPNAME = m.EMPNAME }).ToList()
                        }).ToList();
```